# Controlar las sesiones en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, session

He detectado varios fallos en mis sesiones de laravel y no se sinceramente como solucionarlos.

Cuando me logueo y voy al Home. Si pincho en el botón retroceso de cualquier navegador, me va otra vez a la pantalla de Login. Si meto otra contraseña incorrecta, me sigue yendo al home como si me hubiera logueado correctamente.

Cuando pincho en Remember Me y no hace nada, no se donde debo "mirar" para ver donde no funciona.

Cuando se me agota la sesión, me da un error de sistema. ¿Cómo puedo controlar para que me vaya a un error "amigable"?

Answer (score 0):

para el tema de los Errores amigables laravel trae sus vistas por defecto que también puedes editar, pero que se activan cuando tienes el proyecto en modo producción y APP_DEBUG=false en tu archivo .env. Ahora con el tema de las sesiones podrías crear tus propios middlewares para mitigar los Errores que encuentras, ahí harta documentación de como se implementan los middleware.

Comment: Gracias. Mas o menos se como se implementan los Middleware. Entonces poniendo APP_DEBUG=true, ¿Ya no me salen más errores de sistema?

Comment: APP_ENV=producction
APP_DEBUG=false
ponlo en false

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un middleware usa el siguiente comando remplazando **NewMiddelware** por el nombre de tu middelware.
**php artisan make:middleware NewMiddelware**
y para implementar el middelware en tus rutas te doy el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Route::middleware(['NewMiddelware'])->group(function () {
Route::get('/', function () {
    // Uses first & second middleware...
});
});
```